# Top domain is using subdomain global.asax

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a website on domain www.xyz.com in ASP.NET 2.0

I also have several other websites running on subdomain and on of it is www.abc.ef.xyz.com

Now the global.asax in the subdomain has some code that logs errors by sending emails.

We had some problem on the www.xyz.com, and I started getting emails for errors for this website.

xyz.com has global.asax as well but no where in the code I am sending any error emails.

Any idea how/why this is happening?

Note: I don't have access to server itself i.e. I won't be able to provide info on webserver settings. Though it is a private server(2008/IIS7.5) and not on any hosting provider.

Comment: I think the devil could be in the detail of "_We had some problem on the www.xyz.com_" - if said problem bubbled up to the sub-domains, then the events in their respective `Global.asax` would have been triggered.

Comment: How can you be sure that those are emails for your www.xyz.com site?

Comment: @Window, yes I think the same and want to learn more about it. Any documents or more explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy, because while logging the errors, I am grabbing the domain name. Also most of the errors were page not found and that is pointing to the page that only exists in the www.xyz.com and not in the subdomian. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without access to the server, it would be hard to guess what is going on.  I would imagine that you just have folders separating sites and not actual applications (defined in IIS) that would determine the bounds of what global.asax file is getting read.  I would get a better feel for how the architecture is at the IIS level before going too far in the code level.

Comment: The main site and the subdomain sites are working fine. So the sites should be actudal applications otherwise it would throw an error right? This happened when we had some issue while pushing some changes on main domain site. Users were trying to access the website and since it was down, I kept getting error emails saying /default.aspx not found, and similar. Now my email also logs the domain name and it shows my main domain xyz.com. But I know the email aren't sent from that site. Thanks.